# How to send the header along with payload in Solace

Tags: solace

We have requirement to send header information too along with payload to Solace. How can we achieve this?

Comment: Can you clarify which API (such as C, .NET, Java, MQTT, REST, etc) are you trying to use. Also, an example of your header would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Solace messages allow users to set custom user property (a.k.a header) fields along with the message payload. It is usually required to first insert the desired headers into a Structured Data Map (SDTMap) and then set the SDTMap as the user property section of the message.

---

**Java**

`XMLMessage.setProperties()`

**C**

`solClient_msg_createUserPropertyMap()`

**.NET**

`IMessage.CreateUserPropertyMap()`

For the above 3 APIs, you might find the "Creating Custom Message Header Fields" section in the API guide useful.
https://sftp.solacesystems.com/Portal_Docs/#page/Solace_Messaging_APIs_Developer_Guide/Using_Structured_Data.html#ww607779

---

**JavaScript**

`message.setUserPropertyMap(map);`

**Silverlight**

`message.UserPropertyMap = map;`

**ActionScript**

`message.UserPropertyMap = map;`

For Web-based APIs, you might find the "Creating User Property Maps" section in the Web Messaging API guide useful.
https://sftp.solacesystems.com/Portal_Docs/#page/Solace_Web_Messaging_APIs_Developer_Guide/Using_Structured_Data_Types.html#ww619248

---

**REST**

Include a HTTP header of this format: `Solace-User-Property-<name>: <value>`

You will find "Solace Message Custom Properties" section of the Rest Messaging protocol guide helpful.
https://sftp.solacesystems.com/Portal_Docs/#page/REST_Messaging_Protocol_Guide/2_Solace_REST_Message_Encoding.html#wwpID0E0DN0HA

---

**JMS**

Use standard JMS methods to set message headers.
For example, `Message.setStringProperty(String name, String value)`