# Steps for publishing message to Solace

Tags: java, messaging, middleware, solace

I have heard about Solace and I'm reading about it but I don't know much yet about it. I have a HashMap:

```
{Swaps_snaptime=2016-04-26T07:00:00.000Z, Swaps_20Y=2036-04-29 0.004588, Swaps_15Y=2031-04-29}
```

And I want to publish this to Solace. How do I do that? What are the steps I need to follow? Please help!

Answer (score 2):

You need to execute the following tasks to send a message:

1. Connect to the Solace Message Router
2. Create a producer
3. Create the message object
4. Send the message

There's a simple example of how to do the above at the [Solace website](http://dev.solacesystems.com/get-started/java-tutorials/publish-subscribe_java/).

Note that the example makes use of TextMessages.
In order to send your map, you can do the following:

1. Serialize your map, and then send it as part of a [BytesMessage](https://sftp.solacesystems.com/Portal_Docs/API__Developer_Online_Reference_Documentation/java/com/solacesystems/jcsmp/BytesMessage.html).
2. Place the contents of your map into a [MapMessage](https://sftp.solacesystems.com/Portal_Docs/API__Developer_Online_Reference_Documentation/java/com/solacesystems/jcsmp/MapMessage.html).
3. Place the contents of your map into a [StreamMessage](https://sftp.solacesystems.com/Portal_Docs/API__Developer_Online_Reference_Documentation/java/com/solacesystems/jcsmp/StreamMessage.html)
4. Use any message type, and place the contents of your map into the header portion of the message. Refer to [How to send the header along with payload in Solace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36443418/how-to-send-the-header-along-with-payload-in-solace).